# Prove verification of "if $\lim \inf a_n=\lim \sup a_n=x$ then $a_n$ converges to $x$"

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I know there are proofs of this statement on the website but I was wondering if my, seemingly too simple proof is valid or not.

Assume that $\lim \inf a_n=\lim \sup a_n=x$

We know that $\inf_{k\leq n} a_k\leq a_n\leq\sup_{k\leq n}a_k$ which by squeeze theorem means $a_n$ converges to x. Is this correct?

This seems way too easy, all other proofs I have seen seem to use the definition.

Comment: Do you mean $\inf_{n \geq k} a_n\leq a_k \leq\sup_{n \geq k} a_n$?

Comment: @ParthivBasu Yeah, didnt know how to write that :P

Comment: @ParthivBasu What do you mean, you want the $\inf\{a_k | k\leq n\}$ no?

Comment: It should be $\inf_{k\geq n} a_k \leq a_n\leq\sup_{k \geq n}a_k$ and not $\inf_{k\leq n} a_n\leq a_n\leq\sup_{k\leq n}a_n$. Then you let $n \to \infty$.